# Unable to install mean-cli in linux mint 17 using npm

Tags: linux, node.js, mean.io

I have npm, nodejs installed already. But when I try installing the mean-cli (on linux mint 17)I get the following error. From the error it does seem like the install script for mean-cli is using the command 'node' vs 'nodejs' (for linux-mint). I am not sure how to get it to use the right command.

I searched through google and posts related to mean.io here at SO but couldn't find any pertinent info. Any help is appreciated.

```
sudo npm install -g mean-cli

> mean-cli@0.10.14 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
> node ./scripts/preinstall

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 127
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: You can create a symlink to `node` named `nodejs` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @pacholik - Thanks, that worked. But wouldn't this interfere with the 'actual' 'node' or anything that's looking for it? Anyway, this inquiry is just precautionary as I don't have the other 'node' package installed.

Comment: Yes, it would. But as the matter of fact, when I looked for contents of Ubuntu packages that would colide, I found `nodejs-legacy`, will post as an answer.

Comment: Remove your symlink beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install package `nodejs-legacy`, it is just symlink to `nodejs`.